# Newest records for a SOQL Query

Tags: soql, query, date

I have the Object Case and the Object Agent and I have multiple Agents created by Case. Both of them have their Ids.

Agent has a field CaseId and I want a List with the newest Agents related with a case. How can I make that query?? Now in my List I have:

> Agent with Id ='1', CaseId ='40'
>
> Agent with Id ='2', CaseId ='40'
>
> Agent with Id = '3', CaseId ='40'

**For a Case with Id ='40'**

> Agent with Id ='4', CaseId ='50'
>   Agent with Id = '5', CaseId ='50'

**For a Case with Id = '50'**

AND I want a list with the following Agents:

Agent with Id ='2', CaseId ='40', Agent with Id = '5', CaseId ='50'

**One Agent per Case, the newest Agents using the field CreatedDate**

I have tried that:

```
List <Agent> agents = [SELECT Id, CaseId, MAX(CreatedDate) FROM Agent GROUP BY WorkItemId];
```

But is giving me the following error:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: Field must be grouped or aggregated: Id
```

Is there any way??

A lot of thanks.

Comment: Can you use 'ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC' ? Also your query fetches from AgentWork , but you are trying to store result in in List?Agent>

Comment: When I do that It retrieves:  MALFORMED_QUERY: Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated: CreatedDate

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that using an aggregate query on `Agent` is the right approach here. Aggregate functions and the `GROUP BY` keyword are meant to aggregate data about a group of records (what is the maximum value of field X for this group of records?) rather than pull out a single record from a group.

What you're looking for here, assuming that `CaseId` is a lookup or master-detail relationship field, is a *parent-child subquery*.

The general form of that would be

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM <child relationship name here>) FROM <parent object name here>]
```

This helps you out *because you can use things like `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` in the subquery*.

If you only want the most recently created child record for a parent, that query would look like

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM <child relationship name here> ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM <parent object name here>]
```

Subqueries in the `SELECT` clause will cause a `List<SObject>` to be embedded in the query results for the parent object.

The "child relationship name" is usually the *plural* of the child object's name (with "__r" at the end if the relationship field is a custom field). Finding what the "child relationship name" that you need to use can be done with some anonymous apex.

```java
// A Case has a relationship to Account, the field is called AccountId
// What is the child relationship name?

// We can find that out by using the "describe" information
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsor = Schema.SObjectType.Account;

// The SObject describe information has getChildRelationships(), which gives us a list of
//   the child relationships
for(Schema.ChildRelationship childRel :dsor.getChildRelationships()){
    // getChildSObject() returns an SObject token.
    // We could get the describe information, and then use a method to get the object name
    //   as a string... but we can directly compare to <SObject name>.SObjectType
    //   (which also gives us an SObject token).
    // Similar story for childRel.getField()
    if(childRel.getChildSObject() == Case.SObjectType && childRel.getField() == Case.AccountId){
        system.debug(childRel.getRelationshipName()); // Should print "Cases"
    }
}
```

Once you have the child relationship name, things are pretty simple.

```java
// Query for Accounts, and also get the most recent Case related to each of those Accounts
List<Account> myAccounts = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Cases ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Account LIMIT 100];

// The subquery means that each Account will have a List<Case> associated with it.
// We can get the list of cases using the child relationship name like it were any other field
Account firstAccount = myAccounts[0];
List<Case> firstAccountCases = firstAccount.cases;

// The subquery can return an empty list (just like a regular query), but it will never be null.

// There are issues with retrieving subquery results if there are too many child records
//   and Salesforce needs to perform an internal call to queryMore().
// The way around that issue is to access child records via a nested loop.
// A Map<Id, List<Case>> (where the key is the account Id) can be used to store the result
//   in a useful way
Map<Id, List<Case>> accountIdToCases = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();
for(Account myAcc :myAccounts){
    accountIdToCases.put(myAcc.Id, new List<Case>());
    for(Case childCase :myAcc.cases){
        accountIdToCases.get(myAcc.Id).add(childCase);
    }
}
```

If you only need a list of the most recent cases, and don't care about which Account it's related to, then you could use a simple `List<Case>` instead of a `Map<Id, List<Case>>`.

You can also query for parent fields in your subquery, e.g. `Account.Owner.Name`

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to write Aggregate query which cannot be assigned to list

```
AggregateResult[] lstAggregareResult = [SELECT WorkItemId, Id, CaseId, MAX(CreatedDate) FROM Agent GROUP BY WorkItemId];
```

and then you can iterate over aggregate list for further computation as:

```
for(AggregateResult objAggre: lstAggregareResult ){   

}
```

Comment: When I do that It says MALFORMED_QUERY: Field must be grouped or aggregated: Id

Comment: Add WorkItemId in the query as:

AggregateResult[] lstAggregareResult = [SELECT WorkItemId, Id, CaseId, MAX(CreatedDate) FROM Agent GROUP BY WorkItemId];

Comment: Yes, I have done that but It retrieves that error